# Cut off text using DrawString in TableLayoutPanel

Tags: vb.net, winforms, printing, width, tablelayoutpanel

I'm trying to cut off some text that's inside a TableLayoutPanel.

This is the code i've been using to print the TableLayoutPanel:

```
Dim sf = New StringFormat()
For Each ctrl As Control In TableLayoutPanel.Controls
sf.Alignment = If(TableLayoutPanel.GetColumn(ctrl) < 2, StringAlignment.Near, StringAlignment.Far)
e.Graphics.DrawString(ctrl.Text, ctrl.Font, Brushes.Black, 
Panel.PointToClient(TableLayoutPanel.PointToScreen(ctrl.Bounds.Location)), sf)
Next
```

I've been at this for a couple of hours but i can't seem to get it right.

The labels that are inside the TableLayoutPanel have the properties, Autosize = false and Width = 100.

But DrawString doesn't do anything with it.

I've also looked at the sf. options sf.Trimming = StringTrimming.EllipsisWord and the e.Graphics.MeasureString options but nothing works.

Can somebody please give me a example how to deal with this?
Thank you for your time!

Comment: When drawing, provide the bounding rectangle of the part, not a Point.

Comment: Can you please give me an example?

Comment: `Panel.RectangleToClient(ctrl.RectangleToScreen(ctrl.ClientRectangle))` -- I suggest you use a tool to build a Report template (RDLC or similar).